# i need help i cant load images in pygame i have the images in the right location

Tags: pygame

For some reason I can't load Images to pygame I have tried and it has worked. Here is the code
I am sure the image is in the right file
I need a lot of help plz help I am new to this kind of stuff

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

playerImg = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")

playerX = 350
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0


running = True;
while running:
    
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    playerX += 0.2

    def player(x, y):
        screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
            player(playerX, playerY)
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: It did not give me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the function to draw the image inside the main loop, but the code is not actually calling the draw:

```
running = True;
while running:
    
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    playerX += 0.2

    def player(x, y):                            # <<-- HERE
        screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))           # <<-- HERE

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
            player(playerX, playerY)
            pygame.display.update()
```

Probably just moving the function outside the main loop, and calling it from the loop will work:

```
import pygame

def player( screen, x, y ):                              # <<-- HERE
    """ Draw the player bitmap at x,y """
    screen.blit( playerImg, ( x, y ) )


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

playerImg = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
playerX = 350
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0

# Main Loop    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True;
while running:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    playerX += 0.2
            
    player( screen, playerX, playerY )   # <<-- HERE
   
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick( 60 )  # limit FPS
```